# Javascript function stops other function working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/

The problem bit of code is here I think:

```
$(".nav").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var divId = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top;
    }, 500);}
});
```

I think I have done something wrong with my bracketing because it doesn't seem to scroll correctly or even allow the persistent header to remain persistent. Can anyone show me where I went wrong please?

Comment: what problem you having now?

Comment: You have 2 `{` and 3 `}` in that bit of code. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out which `}` to remove. In fact you have 2 correct choices.

Comment: The chrome developers console will help you in the future.

Comment: When I remove the first or second bracket here ```}, 500);}``` it still doesnt work! I don't understand what lint is trying to tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the error from the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

The reason is because of `;` after you've set the `scrollTop` value, you just need to remove it and it should work:

```
scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top;
// ---                          ^ remove this
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCb5z/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the spurious semicolon after .top

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top}, 500);
```

you might want to wrap the whole content thing in a div with a height and use overflow:auto to keep the menu

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7cZG7/

Also change the fiddle to head instead of onload

Comment: Thank you for the help. May I ask about your suggestion of keeping the content in a div using overflow: auto, what is the advantage of that?

Comment: Look in the fiddle. It will keep the menu in place